# Secure boot screen pops up. How do I get past it?

Tags: upgrade

Hi what do I need to do to get past the secure boot screen? It says to press ok but the screen just keeps popping up.  Anyone help please???!!

Comment: Go into bios and disable it ?

Answer (score 1):

Go into BIOS and disable "Secure Boot".